# Cómo extraer numero de un archivo de texto?

Tags: python

Quiero imprimir por pantalla todas las palabras que coincidan con mi variable (a) dentro de un TXT.

```
a = "FFN"
```

Tengo el siguiente código pero lo único que hace es imprimir todas las líneas del archivo:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    a = "FFN"
    for line in f:
        for a in line.split():
            print(a)
```

Contenido de archivo.txt:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646817 P1k200 SYNFP4 STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646819 P1k2952 STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646818 SYNFP4
```

Lo que obtengo al ejecutar el código es lo siguiente:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646817
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646819
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646818
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es el numero que sigue a mi variable a, tal que así:

```
1646817
1646819
1646818
```

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT

Suprimiendo la línea del split, he conseguido que solamente me imprima las líneas en las que se encuentra el contenido de mi variable:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
a = 'FFN'
for line in f:
    if a in line:
        print (a)
```

Salida:

```
FFN
FFN
```

**Lo único que me hace falta ahora es imprimir los números que siguen al FFN de cada línea, como podría hacer esto teniendo en cuenta que los números pueden cambiar cada vez que ejecuto el código?**

Comment: Vuelvo a formular la pregunta ya que en la otra no recibía respuestas que se ajustaran a lo que pedía.

Comment: no vuelvas a preguntar lo mismo, estás haciendo flaco favor al sitio y a la gente que intentó ayudarte. En lugar de eso, edita la pregunta original y clarifica qué es lo que falla. En su momento fuiste añadiendo detalles del fichero a cuentagotas y dejando fuera elementos importantes para la solución, por favor tenlo en cuenta de cara al futuro

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' esta pregunta SI tiene una respuesta adecuada a lo que se pregunta, la anterior no, esta puede ayudar a alguien si lo necesitase, la otra NO.

Comment: Con independencia de que la respuesta en esta publicación sea mas o menos adecuada, en el sitio no se permite repetir preguntas solo por el hecho de que la anterior haya recibido menos atención o peores respuestas. Por lo que veo tal vez el problema es que tu pregunta original no era en origen tan detallada por lo que la respuesta que hay allí se ajusto a la información original. Lo que te comenta @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' es que para próximas ocasiones tengas esto en cuenta: las normas no permiten repetir preguntas, si editar la pregunta original para añadir toda la información necesaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes muchas formas de hacer lo que buscas, según cómo sean realmente las líneas de tu fichero.

#### Solución simple

Si puedes asegurar que en todos los casos la estructura es tan simple como en el ejemplo que has mostrado, es decir, que tras el texto FFN y hasta el final de la línea, lo único que aparecen son los dígitos del número que buscas, entonces la cosa es muy sencilla.

Bastaría "romper" la línea por el punto en que aparece FFN, y quedarse con el último trozo de los resultantes. Es decir:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
  a = 'FFN'
  for line in f:
    if a in line:
        num = line.split(a)[-1]
        print(num)
```

Eso te dejaría en `num` la cadena de caracteres que buscas, que sería todo lo que hay desde FFN hasta el final de la línea. Si necesitas esos números para operar con ellos (por ejemplo, sumarlos todos) deberás usar `int(num)`, pues de lo contrario estarías operando con cadenas.

#### Solución más general con expresiones regulares

Si la sintaxis te las líneas puede ser más variable, por ejemplo, que tras la cadena FFN aparezca una secuencia de dígitos, pero después de ella puedan aparecer otros caracteres que debas descartar, en este caso podría ser más adecuado usar expresiones regulares. Las expresiones regulares son en general difíciles de escribir, de leer y de depurar, por lo que mejor evitarlas si es posible. Pero en este caso la expresión a usar no sería muy compleja.

```
import re

with open("data.txt") as f:
  for linea in f:
    m = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
    if m: 
      print(m.group(1))
```

Por ejemplo, con una entrada como esta:

```
Esta no interesa
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646817aquihaymascosas
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646819algomas
Esta tampoco interesa
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646818
Ni esta
```

Producirá la la salida:

```
1646817
1646819
1646818
```

(que de nuevo serían cadenas de texto pero puedes convertir a `int()`)

#### Explicación

La expresión regular utilizada es `FFN(\d+)`, que significa:

- La cadena FFN seguida de un "grupo de captura" (la expresión entre paréntesis)
- El grupo de captura se compone de uno o más dígitos seguidos (el `\d` representa un dígito, y el `+` significa "el carácter anterior aparece una o más veces")

Si la línea no encaja con esa expresión (no contiene FFN seguido de dígitos), el valor retornado por `re.search()` será `None`, y entonces esa línea no produce resultado. Si encaja, entonces el valor retornado en `m` será un objeto que tiene un método `.group()` que permite acceder a lo que se guardó en el "grupo de captura", es decir, la secuencia de dígitos buscada.

Comment: Lo he probado y lo que ocurre es que me elimina el contenido previo al FFN, pero el texto que hay a continuación me lo sigue imprimiendo. Mi propósito es que después de los números se detenga y salte al siguiente FFN.

Comment: ¿Qiueres decir que en la línea, después del FFN y de los dígitos puede haber más cosas? Eso no coincide entonces con el ejemplo que suministraste. En este caso puede ser más sencillo usar expresiones regulares. He editado la respuesta para poner un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Entiendo que el \d+ se refiere a los dígitos que siguen a la cadena de texto. Hay alguna variante para hacerlo con caracteres?

Comment: Sí, claro. El `.` representa cualquier caracter (sea dígito o no), el `\D` representa cualquier carácter que no sea dígito... hay muchísimas más opciones. Te recomiendo buscar info sobre expresiones regulares (hay mucha documentación y tutoriales en internet, ya que ésta no es una característica exclusiva de Python, sino que muchos lenguajes lo tienen). La web https://regex101.com/ es excelente para hacer pruebas y aprender sobre expresiones regulares. Si necesitas ayuda con una en concreto no dudes en hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: Con el método que has indicado, es posible guardar cada resultado de este print: print(fn.group(1)), en una variable por separado?

Comment: No veo por qué no. Puedes tener una lista inicializada fuera del bucle con `lista = []` y dentro del bucle hacer un `lista.append(fn.group(1))`, por ejemplo, para que al final la lista tenga todos los valores que has recogido.